# cakephp form fields that cannot be modified/edited

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i need to show some fields in my edit views but make it so they cannot be edited

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Edit User'); ?></legend>

<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('ID');
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('account_type');
?>
</fieldset>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
 </div>
```

are there any ways to make use of the ;abel() function or anything so that when i display both id and account type in the view, the values of these fields appear but cannot be edited?

Comment: Note that `ID` != `id`. You should try to stick to the conventions here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use disabled attribute of plain html input tag.

```
echo $this->Form->input('account_type', array('disabled'=>'disabled'));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things wrong in your form.

1. The id should not be editable
2. The id field is really uppercase? (case here is important)

Ok, now if you want your inputs to be enable to editing you can force it via the disabled attribute as @Abhishek told. But you have to set it to false. So your form should be like this:

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Edit User'); ?></legend>

<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('id', array('disabled'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('username', array('disabled'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('account_type', array('disabled'=>false));
?>
</fieldset>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
 </div>
```